# Need help with naming substate

Tags: naming, naming-standards

I'm designing an application which accepts a command, processes it and produces a result. Application will maintain the status of the input command as 'new', 'processing' and 'completed' as it transition through the execution flow.

When the command processing is completed, status will be updated to 'completed'. But it can be completed with either success, failed or ignored. I need a proper name for these substates - success, failure or ignore. Should I call them 'result' or 'statusCode'.

```
new, inprogress and completed -> status
success, failed and ignored -> ????
```

Comment: `resultStatus`, something with `result` or `completionDegree` (allowing negatives like `failed` / `ignored`.

Comment: They indicate the status of the completed state, so call then `completedState` or `completedStatus` or the like. Do not ever, please, use `statusCode`. That just tells me I have a code that represents a status, ie it's almost completely devoid of information.

Comment: This makes sense. I'll go with `completedState`

Answer (score 1):

These sound like two different things, so I would be inclined to keep them as separate as possible, probably `command.progress` and `command.completionState` then you can have four `completionState` values, `incomplete, success, failed, ignored` which would cover all the possible outcomes or indicate no outcome was yet available and whatever `progress` statuses you need to introduce as time goes on - there's a very good chance those will proliferate as system complexity increases.

Comment: Great. This was helpful